# Using Python or adb command to read Android UI text?

Tags: android, python, automation, adb, screen-readers

I was just wondering if there was a way to read the text displayed on a Android device's UI using python or any adb commands?

I have found a module for python called "UIAutomator : https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator", which can be used to dump the screen's contents, but it seems to be really slow and often unreliable in terms of connection to the android device.

I also found google's own UIAutomator tool, but I needed something that can be used via a python script or an adb command to read the onscreen text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

I have done a bit of research and found out two ways to read the UI's contents.

1. Using AndroidViewClient's dump tool.

This is their project page : https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient

This tutorial helped me set up AndroidViewClient : https://www.darpandodiya.com/code/setup-androidviewclient-windows/

2. Using this adb command :

This command saves the UI Heirarchy XML in the device's sdcard.
`adb exec-out uiautomator dump`

This gives the result in the console itself. `adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty`

Comment: Is there a possibility to retrieve the UI text which is dynamically created. The last command works for me but some elements which are created dynamically are missing.